# What is the difference between tf.train.AdamOptimizer and use adam in keras.compile?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, keras

i was building a dense neural network for predicting poker hands. First i had a problem with the reproducibility, but then i discovered my real problem: That i can not reproduce my code is because of the adam-optimizer, because with sgd it worked.
This means

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

did NOT work, whereas

```
opti = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opti, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

worked with reproducibility.
So my question is now:
Is there any difference using

```
tf.train.AdamOptimizer
```

and

```
model.compile(..., optimizer = 'adam')
```

because i would like to use the first one because of the reproduce-problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "reproducilbility"? As to my knowledge, `keras` is just an API for the backend engine which is `tensorflow` by default. So, whenever you're using `adam`, you're using `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` according to the official implementation [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/activations.py#L211).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both are the same. However, in the tensorflow.train.AdamOptimizer you can change the learning rate

```
tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(
    learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, use_locking=False,
    name='Adam')
```

which will improve the learning performance and the training would take longer. but in the **model.compile(optimizer="adam")** it will set the learning rate, beta1, beta2...etc to the default settings